# Die Verwendung von "dass nachdem"

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

> Ich weiß, dass nachdem er einen Job bekommen hat, er sich einen Audi kaufte.

Kann man die zwei Konjunktionen in einem Satz schreiben?

Comment: Mit korrekter Kommasetzung kann man das.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In diesem Beispiel stehen die beiden Konjunktionen vor *zwei verschiedenen*
geschachtelten Sätzen:

> Ich weiß, (dass, (nachdem er einen Job bekommen hat,) er sich einen Audi kaufte.)

Die Satzstruktur wird klarer, wenn man die Bestandteile umdreht:

> Ich weiß, dass er sich einen Audi kaufte, nachdem er einen Job bekommen hat.

Comment: Und deshalb gehört auch ein Komma vor _nachdem_.